# How to obtain a certain value from a map list and reference that value in IAM policy terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

So I have an IAM policy where I am hard coding the name of the IAM group. Instead, I want to be able to reference the arn of a specific group. I have the following configuration set up :

**variables.tf**

```
variable "iam_user_groups" {
  type        = map(list(string))
  description = "The iam user groups variables"
}
```

**IAM Groups Resource**

```
resource "aws_iam_group" "data_engineers_team" {
  for_each = var.iam_user_groups
  name     = "${local.csi}-${each.key}"
  path     = "/"
}
```

**groups.tfvars**

```
iam_user_groups = {
  all-users = ["user1@gmail.com",],
  admin-team = ["user1-admin@gmail.com",],
  operational-team = [ ],
}
```

**outputs.tf**

```
output "map_group_arn" {
  value = { for k, v in aws_iam_group.data_engineers_team : k => v.group_arn }
}
```

This is my IAM Policy :

```
    condition {
      test     = "StringNotEquals"
      variable = "aws:PrincipalArn"
      values   = ["arn:aws:iam::${var.aws_account_id}:group/admin-team"]
    }
```

I only want the arn of **admin-team**.At the moment I have this hardcoded which is not best practice.

I have tried to obtain just the admin-team arn but the solution I currently have loops through all iam-user groups.

Comment: Where do you want to get that value from? Output that you have defined?

Comment: So I was thinking from the output i have defined , somehow I can obtain just the arn of user group admin-team @MarkoE

Comment: Can you add the group resource definition to the question as well? Are the groups and the policy in the same terraform module?

Comment: Yes the IAM resource  , variables.tf , outputs.tf and the IAM policy are in in the same directory which is called account @MarkoE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the data in the question, the group ARN should be easy to fetch from the attributes exported by the IAM group resource:

```
condition {
  test     = "StringNotEquals"
  variable = "aws:PrincipalArn"
  values   = [aws_iam_group.data_engineers_team["admin-team"].arn]
}
```

Comment: my tfvars is not in the same directory but in a folder called etc so that shouldn't be a  problem. Let me test this out and see what this will output

Comment: Well, that is why I asked about where the files were. Not sure why are you keeping the tfvars file away from the other code, but you can solve that by providing the path to the file when calling terraform commands from the CLI.